# Is my proof of the identity $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})=-\ln(1-x)$ correct?

Tags: calculus, power-series, solution-verification

This post is inspired by this question [Justifying $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\log(1+x^{2^n}) = -\log(1-x)$ for $0\le x<1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774804/justifying-sum-n-0-infty-log1x2n-log1-x-for-0-le-x1)

Also this is the crucial step in the second official solution (justified differently there) to Putnam 2016 problem B6.

**A Power-Series Proof**

We know that $$\ln(1+t)=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{t^m}{m}$$
Therefore $$\ln(1+x^{2^n})=\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}$$ Hence
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})=\color{red}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}=\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}}$$
Consider the series $$f(z):=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{2^n}$$ Then we get $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})=\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\frac{(-1)^{m-1}}{m}f(x^m)$$

Note that $$f(z^2)=f(z)-z\tag{1}$$ Denote $$E=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x^{2k})}{2k}$$ and $$O=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x^{2k-1})}{2k-1}$$ Then $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})=O-E\tag{2}$$ Again from $(1)$ we get

$$E=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x^{2k})}{2k}=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x^k)-x^k}{2k}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f(x^k)}{k}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^k}{k}=\frac{O+E}{2}+\frac{\ln(1-x)}{2}$$
Therefore $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})=O-\frac{O+E}{2}-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{2}=\frac{O-E}{2}-\frac{\ln(1-x)}{2}$$
$$\implies\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})=\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})}{2}-\ln(1-x)\tag{from (2)}$$
$$\implies\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\ln(1+x^{2^n})=-\ln(1-x)\tag*{$\square$}$$

**Edit**

Since, for $x\in[0,1)$, the double series $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}$$ is absolutely convergent, we can split the sum in the following way and can observe why is it possible to swap the order of summation in the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ part above

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n2k}}{2k}+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n(2k-1)}}{(2k-1)}\right)\\=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n2k}}{2k}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n(2k-1)}}{(2k-1)}\\=-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n2k}}{2k}+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n(2k-1)}}{(2k-1)}$$
We can interchange the order of summation due to the non-negativity of the summands and hence it becomes,
$$=\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}$$

We have used Tonelli's theorem for changing the order of infinite sums with non-negative summands.

Comment: How do you justify this step? $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}=\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}$$

Comment: Depending on the situation, you may need to justify things like the interchange of summation. If these things are acceptable without justification, it seems correct. (I haven't _carefully_ checked, so I might have missed something.)

Comment: @DanielFischer $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n2k}}{2k}+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n(2k-1)}}{(2k-1)}\right)\\=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n2k}}{2k}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^{2^n(2k-1)}}{(2k-1)}\\=-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n2k}}{2k}+\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2^n(2k-1)}}{(2k-1)}\\\text{(can interchange due to non-negativity of the summands)}\\=\sum^{\infty}_{m=1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{m-1}\frac{x^{2^nm}}{m}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer is this way of verifying that, we can change the order of summation, correct?

Comment: I know, I'm just saying that there are situations (when you're a student handing in an assignment, or when you're a professor presenting it to undergraduates, for example) where you need to provide a justification. If it can be safely assumed that all persons involved immediately see that the double series is absolutely convergent, you can skip it.

Comment: Yeah, I understood it. Thanks! @DanielFischer

Comment: For that, you also need to justify why you can split the sum.

Comment: @DanielFischer How can I justify that we can split the sum?

Comment: Probably the fastest/most straightforward way is absolute convergence. For $0 \leqslant x < 1$, $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2^nm}}{m} < +\infty\,.$$

Comment: Ohh, yes! I got it. Thanks for your help. Now it's all clear to me.